# python dictionary into sqlite

Tags: python, json, sqlite, dictionary

I have built a sqlite db and table in Python 2.7 with 6 variables, based on reading a URL file.

I used JSON and created a dictionary. The code reads everything well and loops through the keys and values.

I need to insert this into my table. That is where I am a little lost. I will provide the code and I think my hole will be obvious.

```
import json
import urllib2
#Read file and print a line
webFD=urllib2.urlopen("http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment4.txt")
tweet = webFD.readline()
tweet


#create dictionary
dictt=json.loads(tweet)

#print dictionary
dictt.keys()

#print values
dictt.values()

#loop through tweets
for (key, value) in dictt.items():
    print key, '->', value

#Created the DB
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Created the table for the tweets
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Tweet(created_at, id, text, source,    in_reply_to_user_ID,retweet_Count)")
```

Here is my disconnect. Want to load those tweets (6 keys and values in the dict into the Tweet tables:

```
for elt in tweet:
    currentRow = elt[:-1].split(", ")
    insert = """insert into Tweet values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" %("created_at", "id", "text", 'source', 'in_reply_to_user_ID', 'retweet_Count')
    print insert
```

Comment: We don't know what the source data looks like. And that's not how you perform queries in Python.

Comment: It looks like homework problem...

Comment: It is a homework problem, in full disclosure. We were advised (ie given permission) to use Stackoverflow as we got stuck on things.

Comment: @adam It's OK to ask homework questions here. There are no special 'restrictions' to doing so; the standards about quality and the like still apply, and this isn't a bad question at all, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two errors:

- You're retrieving only a tweet
- Some keys of the dict are misspelled (Python is not case insensitive)

Try this. It's not the best solution (it keeps opening/closing the database), but it very similar to the one you posted.

```
import json
import urllib2
#Read file and print a line
webFD = urllib2.urlopen("http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment4.txt")
tweets = webFD.readlines()

for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet


    #create dictionary
    try:
        dictt = json.loads(tweet)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    #print dictionary
    print dictt.keys()

    #print values
    print dictt.values()



    #loop through tweets
    for (key, value) in dictt.items():
        print key, '->', value


    #Created the DB
    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    #Created the table for the tweets
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tweet(created_at, id, text, source,    in_reply_to_user_ID,retweet_Count)")

    #*** Here is a possible solution ***
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Tweet VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
          (dictt['created_at'], dictt["id"], dictt["text"], dictt['source'], dictt['in_reply_to_user_id'],
           dictt['retweet_count']))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This is great. After a few days finally got a tweet to read in. Now, what would I change if I wanted to automate the process and loop and read and load all the tweets in this file?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here makes no sense:

```
insert = """insert into Tweet values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" %("created_at", "id", "text", 'source', 'in_reply_to_user_ID', 'retweet_Count')
```

Using `%`-formatting with literal strings just replaces each `%s` with the literal string. So you'll get this:

```
insert into Tweet values ('created_at', 'id', 'text', 'source', 'in_reply_to_user_ID', 'retweet_Count')
```

And that's obviously nonsense; you want to insert the *values*, not the *column names*.

You *could*—but should not—fix this by putting the six values into the `%` operation, like this:

```
insert = """insert into Tweet values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" % currentRow
```

But this is still a bad idea. What happens if one of those values could have a quote in it? [This](http://xkcd.com/327/).

What you *want* to do is this:

```
c.execute("insert into Tweet values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", currentRow)
```

This lets the database handle formatting the values, making sure they're quoted properly, etc.